# MS Word APIs: Saving .doc word document as .docx in batch mode

Tags: vbscript, ms-word, save-as

I am trying to open a doc file and save it as docx in batch mode. But MSWord is always shows up even when the visible attribute is set to false..

is there something wrong with my code ?

```
If Wscript.Arguments.Count <> 2 Then
 Wscript.Echo "Wrong Arguments. Need 2 arguments; Filename and Output Directory."
 Wscript.quit
End If

Dim objApp
Dim objDoc
Dim objFile

fileName = Wscript.Arguments(0)
outputDirectory = Wscript.Arguments(1)

Set objFSO = CreateObject( "Scripting.FileSystemObject" )
Set MyObject = GetObject(fileName) 
if MyObject is Nothing then 
    objApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Else
    Set objApp = MyObject.Application
End If
objApp.Visible = False
Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(fileName)
Set objDoc = objApp.Documents.Open(fileName)
objDoc.SaveAs objFSO.BuildPath( outputDirectory, objFSO.GetBaseName( objFile ) & ".docx" ), 12
objDoc.Close
objApp.Quit
Set objDoc = Nothing
Set objApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Please make it clear what you are trying to achieve and whats wrong with the current code.

Comment: I am trying to open a doc file and save it as docx but without MSWord being visible. But MSWord is always visible.

Comment: Please try to include this in the question title and in the question itself instead of a comment.

Comment: 1. Add `Set ` to `objApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")`, 2. Change all `MyObject` to `objApp`? 3. Shouldn't `".docx"` be outside of `objFSO.BuildPath()`? What you should do is use the Word VBE to ensure the word macros are working, then convert it to VBS (you can use FSO in VBA)!